# Only One Error Message from a Failed Promise Chain in Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, promise

If I chain my promises as follows,

```
var promise1 = step1(), 
    promise2 = promise1.then(function(data) {
                 return step2();
               }), 
    promise3 = promise2.then(function(data) {
                 return step3();
               });
```

I also separately have Fail messages for each step. The GUI should display error messages when an error happens,

```
    promise1.fail(function(data) {
        alert('A system error occurred and your action could not be completed. Please try again. Data: ' + data);
    });
    promise2.fail(function(data) {
        alert('A system error occurred and your action could not be completed. Please try again. Data: ' + data);
    });         
    promise3.fail(function(data) {
        alert('A system error occurred and your action could not be completed. Please try again. Data: ' + data);
    });
```

I don't want to propagate multiple error messages if something happens in Promise3. The GUI should only display one error from the whole chain. Is this possible?

Comment: Uh, just don't have separate fail messages on every promise? `promise3` will get rejected anyway if there's an error anywhere in your chain, so just use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to break the chain with intermediate assignments.

Write it as a single semantic chain,

```
var promise = step1()
.then(function(data1) {
    return step2();
})
.then(function(data2) {
    return step3();
})
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert('A system error occurred and your action could not be completed. Please try again. error: ' + textStatus);
});
```

An error in `step1()`, `step2()` or `step3()` will cause the rest of the success path to be skipped and will percolate down to the fail handler at the end.

That appears to be what you want.